# Retrieve People or Group Field to string instead of Object

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

Iam retrieving an item from my list with jsom in a script editor. i retrieve a field wich is the type of: user or group field. I want to display the group name i retrieve.

I tryied to parse to json, but the output is this then:

GroupName = {"$1Q_1":27,"$4A_1":"myGroup"}

How can i just get my name of the group: "myGroup" in this example?

Comment: there are methods to getting things parsed from json. how are you retrieving your group? Can you show your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JSOM as:

```
var groupName  = oListItem.get_item("FieldName").get_lookupValue();
var groupId   = oListItem.get_item("FieldName").get_lookupId();
```

Comment: Thank you. i use the method, getByName. So i will go for get_lookupValue();. Thanks

Comment: If it works, please mark answer as correct to close the question..

Comment: Yes, i had to wait 4 min before i could do that :)

Answer (score 0):

yes help a lot 
function retrieveListItemsInclude() {

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');
    alert('entra'+ oList);
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

```
var listItemInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

 while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
        '\nContact: ' + oListItem.get_item('Contact').get_lookupValue()+
         '\nDescription: ' + oListItem.get_item('Description') ; 

}
alert(listItemInfo.toString());
```

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

```
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
```

}